# Active Record query error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, rails-activerecord

This query throws an error:

```
EncodingPreset.where('default = ?', false)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "default"
LINE 1: ...coding_presets".* FROM "encoding_presets"  WHERE (default = ...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "encoding_presets".* FROM "encoding_presets"  WHERE (default = 'f')
```

but this works:

```
EncodingPreset.where(:default => false)
```

Why is the first query not working?

Versions:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194
activerecord-3.2.11
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because default is a keyword and has to be put in quotes for use in a query.
This should work:

```
EncodingPreset.where('"default" = ?', false)
```

Answer (score 3):

**default** is reserved keyword in postgreSQL that's why it throws error.
Change the column name with some other name, then it works